# FOR LOOP within Callback procedure in System.Threading.Timer causes it to fire only ONCE

Tags: c#

At the moment I have a For loop  within a Callaback procedure :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerProc, null, 60000, 60000);

}

public void TimerProc(object state)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        //Do something here
    }

}
```

TimerProc only fires ONCE despite the fact that I have it set to repeat every 60000 milliseconds. It looks like that the operations within the loop are no longer executed after they are completed the first time around.

However, if I remove the For loop and have some other action like print to a console line or write to a text file then TimerProc repeats as expected.

Why is this the case and why does a loop with in a Callback procedure stop it from executing after its initial firing?

I have made a workaround by using a while(true) infinte loop and using the Thread.Timer to pause the process after x amount of milliseconds.

My new vised code with the while loop looks like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{

processthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
processthread.Start();

}

public void DoSomething()

{

  while(true)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
           //do something here

    }
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
  }

}
```

I just want to know why callback procedure in the System.Thread.Timer cannot handle loops.

Cheers,

Stanley

Comment: It's one of differences between System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer.  The first one keeps an internal reference that keeps the object alive as long as the timer is enabled.  You have to do it yourself for System.Threading.Timer

Answer (score 1):

From the code you've included in the question, it *looks* like you aren't storing a reference to `timer` anywhere. I could be wrong, but my guess is that you're not seeing the callback repeated because the timer object itself has been garbage collected. Assign a reference to the timer to a longer-lived variable (i.e., a field) and I'd wager that will resolve the problem.

In other words, I don't think the `for` loop has anything to do with what you're seeing (I'm not disputing the evidence, just proposing that it's coincidental and nothing else).

To test my hypothesis, I created the following very simple Windows Forms app:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Timer = System.Threading.Timer;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new TestForm());
    }
}

class TestForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var timer = new Timer(TimerProc, null, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public void TimerProc(object state)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }
}
```

I saw the current time print to the console for a little more than thirty seconds; then it stopped.

In contrast, the following change appears to resolve the problem.

```
class TestForm : Form
{
    // Note: declare a field to store a reference to the timer.
    Timer timer;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.timer = new Timer(TimerProc, null, 1000, 1000);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I started the program again after making the above change, and the timer has continued firing for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  After discussion with **Dan Tao** it's probably a GC problem due to the lack of a reference.  Adding in the reference fixes the problem [uncomment lines 8 and 20].  The presence of a the 'for loop' in the question probably caused the collection - maybe by generating garbage which explains why removing it and replacing it with a simpler LOC worked for you in this particular instance.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO_TimerTroubles
{
    class Program
    {
        //static Timer t;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartTimer();  //Works fine.
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to BeginGC");
            Console.ReadLine();
            GC.Collect();  //Timer stops.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void StartTimer()
        {
            //t =
            new Timer(TimerProc, null, 1000, 1000);
        }

        static public void TimerProc(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Called");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Original Answer]  The following works fine - I suspect the error is elsewhere.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var timer = new Timer(TimerProc, null, 1000, 1000);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static public void TimerProc(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: But in your example the program terminates after the `Console.ReadLine()`, which means there is a reference to `timer` for the entire lifetime of the application. Whereas the OP's example appears to be from a Windows Forms app, and he initializes the timer with a local that goes out of scope long before the application ends. I believe this is why in your example the timer will continue to run the entire time while in the OP's case it just inexplicably stops.

Comment: @DanTao - Nope, I read your answer and tried it myself by moving the start timer to another function - same result.  So while that could be an issue, I cannot replicate it.

Comment: But that could still be because your test never runs into a garbage collection. Instead of your `Console.ReadLine()` call try allocating memory in a loop or something--anything to force a GC. I'll be interested in finding out the result.

Comment: @DanTao - Force a GC?  How about we try with GC.Collect() :P  Turns out your theory does appear to be correct - the timer without a reference will be collected by the GC - updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! Wow, didn't expect an answer so soon. I'll get it a go :)

Comment: @NPSF3000: Haha, yeah shortly after I posted that comment (right before bed, actually), I was like, *Wait, why didn't I just say to call `GC.Collect()`?* Glad you saw past my dumb suggestion on your own! ;)